# j2me - Does a List have any property to keep track of 'key' that identify the item

Tags: java-me, lcdui

How do you usually deal with Lists and the fact that they don't have a property to clearly identity an specific item ?
So far, the only solucion I could come up with is to put the key I use at the beginning, followed by a hyphen  and the text that is shown on every item.
This way when I retrieve the text from the selected item I can get the key for the item.

This is how I do it, but surely there's gotta be a better solution and I'd really like that you could share your experience in this kind of scenarios.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture ooks like you keep all the data managed in your application inside the text of the items of a standard list.

Better hava a separate class for the data container objects and an overview screen derived from `List` that takes an array of those container objects and instantiate the `Items` from that. This screen could then provide a method

```
DataContainer getSelectedObject()
```

which uses getSelectedIndex() internally to look up the object.

More specifically (Overview.java)

```
package mvc.midlet;

import javax.microedition.lcdui.List;

public class Overview extends List {

    private final DomainObject[] data;
    public static Overview create(DomainObject[] data) {
        int i = 0;
        for(; i < data.length; i++) {
            if(data[i] == null) break;
        }
        String[] names = new String[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            names[j] = data[j].name;
        }
        return new Overview(names, data);
    }

    protected Overview(String names[], DomainObject[] data) {
        super("Overview", IMPLICIT, names, null);
        this.data = data;
    }

    public DomainObject getSelectedObject() {
        return data[this.getSelectedIndex()];
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you Gregor, but do you think you could provide a basic example or explain a little more in detail your approach? Thank you

Comment: Thanks @Gregor. It's not the I want to be spoon-fed, but I'm not sure what you mean by "instantiate the Items from that". I thought Lists can only have string items. Is there any way to store object is List? Do you think you could explain that part??

Comment: @eddy : this is an extension of the Overview from my answer to your [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24119067/how-do-you-organize-your-code-in-a-j2me-project/24150485#24150485)